# Set time in DateTime from another Column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having Date field & by mistake records are updated in the table without setting the timings.

I want to firstly find such records & then update them with timings from the same Table.

[image]

In this image, record for `2018-07-20` doesn't have time so i want to update `In_Time` time to `In_Date` so the output will be `2018-07-20 06:21:00`.

I want to search all such records & update the timings for the same.

Is there any way i can do this with Query?

Comment: What are the types of the `In_Hour` and `Out_Hour` columns?

Comment: `In_Hour` is `string` but `In_Time` is `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By considering that you are storing minutes as integer in `In_Time` and `Out_Time` columns.

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET
In_Date=DATEADD(MINUTE,In_Time,In_Date)
where CAST(In_Date as time(0)) ='00:00:00'



UPDATE [TableName]
SET
Out_Date=DATEADD(MINUTE,Out_Time,Out_Date)
where CAST(Out_Date as time(0)) ='00:00:00'
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thanks. I managed to do in single update statement.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just add the time and date components.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    In_Date = In_Date + CAST(In_Hour AS datetime),
    Out_Date = Out_Date + CAST(Out_Hour AS datetime);
```

The above should work assuming that the date columns are already `datetime`.  Then, casting the hour columns as `datetime` should produce only an hour component.

### Demo

But, I would recommend against storing time and date separately, unless you have a very specific reason for doing so.  Instead, I think just recording the in and out timestamps should be enough for you.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I will try this & let you know. But how to find records which have time `00:00:00` because there are other records also which have timings included which i do not want to update.

Comment: @Anup If the time component is really `00:00:00` then the update I suggested just wouldn't change anything.  I'm not even sure this is an edge case which you need to worry about.